# Navigation bar in page view controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I have this situation :

in my app I have a page view controller within view controllers and navigation controller. I want add right item in navigation bar when appear a particular view controller in page view controller and for this reason I did this in the view controller where I want to add right button:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
      let camera:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Camera, target: self, action: Selector("test"))
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = camera
}
```

but it doesn't work , I don't see the right button.

What do I wrong?

EDIT ONE:

this is my situation in storyboard:

[image]

Comment: So the navigation controller is outside the page view controller and the page view controller is outside this view controller?

Comment: in my answer I added my storyboard

Comment: the page view controller's view controller are added in the code

Comment: Well, that's what I assumed, and my answer explains the issue to you.

Comment: how can I fix it? I have nothing in mind

Comment: how to connect the page view controller's navigation controller and view controller in page view controller?

Comment: Did you read my answer?

Comment: yes sorry but I had not seen the change

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `self.navigationItem` is used only when this view controller is the direct child of a navigation controller. That's not the situation here. The direct child of the navigation controller is some other view controller — maybe the page view controller, or something that contains the page view controller (hard to tell from your description). You need to rethink your approach here. You can do what you want to do, but only by somehow sending a signal to the direct child of the navigation controller and having him configure *his* navigation item.

So, for your configuration, the only view controller whose `navigationItem` can affect the navigation controller automatically is the one with the table view (the navigation controller's direct child) or whoever is pushed on top of it (the one with the pager view controller?).

Comment: sorry I don't understand your solution. when I tap on table view's cell I go in the page view controller and in it there are the various view controllers , when I go in a specific view controller (content in page view controller) how do I refer to table view 's navigation controller?

Comment: Okay, think about it. When this inner view controller appears, the navigation controller is its `navigationController`. And the topmost view controller child of the navigation controller is the navigation controller's `topViewController`. So what you want to do is configure that view controller's `navigationItem`. So you _could_ say `self.navigationController?.topViewController?.navigationItem`. But I do not advise just reaching right in and doing that; you need to come up with a decent architecture for giving each view controller its own proper job. That's why I said "send a signal".

Comment: ok you said that my architecture isn't decent and  I'd like to have some advice where to improve , I am beginner

Comment: The page view controller seems to me to be the key. He is the child of the navigation controller and he is the parent of the view controller that comes into view - and he (or his delegate) knows what view controller comes into view! So _he_ is the one who should have the power to decide what's in his own navigation item.